# Which among #define CONST_STR "my_string" and const char *CONST_STR = "my_string" are memory efficient

Tags: c, c-strings, static-memory-allocation

I need to use the **constant** string "`my_string`" in 100s of lines in my C code.
And I have constraints on final binary size.
**So which one should I go for?**
(I am thinking `const char*` is better because memory allocated to string only once. Am I right...?)

Compiler : `gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)`
Compiler options:  `-fPIC -Wall -g -O2 -pthread -O2 -g`

Comment: In one translation unit? In many translation units? Will the string be used in ways that can be optimized at compile time? E.g., extracting individual characters using constant indices? Show examples. Which compiler? Which version? With which compilation switches?

Comment: In a single translation unit, defining a character array with `const my_string[] = "my_string";` is likely to use the least memory. It guarantees the compiler knows `my_string` is one place in memory, whereas using a string literal `"my_string"` multiple times does not guarantee the compiler will not replicate it, although good compilers generally should not. But there can still be complications.

Comment: In case you are using the very same string literal at multiple times then most compilers are able to do "string pooling" optimizations, only allocating it once.

Comment: Hey @EricPostpischil I am not sure about the translation unit, but I am generating a shared object (.so) out of it. And these string are used only as help string to be printed only.

Comment: You might want to replace `-O2` with `-Os` which will optimize for size.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an answer but...

I don't think that you should worry about this at all.  The compiler is much smarter than we are and will do the best thing.  You're going to waste a lot of your time trying to optimize string literals.

Just code in a way that makes sense to you.

However, it's worth noting that if you're trying to optimize for size you might want to use the -Os option instead of -O2

> -Os Optimize for size. -Os enables all -O2 optimizations except those that often increase code size:
>
> -falign-functions  -falign-jumps
> -falign-labels  -falign-loops
> -fprefetch-loop-arrays  -freorder-blocks-algorithm=stc It also enables -finline-functions, causes the compiler to tune for code size rather than execution speed, and performs further optimizations designed to
> reduce code size.

[GCC Optimize Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)

Answer (score 0):

With the right compiler optimisation settings you won't see any difference in the amount of memory used.

One point that is consistently missed though is that the use of `const` variables rather than `#defines` greatly improves the ease of locating coding errors related to them.

In fact the compiler itself will aid you in preventing the introduction of bugs, as it will also perform type checking during compilation on the use of a `const` variables, whereas they invariably don't on `#define`.

That is not to say that there isn't a place for `#define` just that they shouldn't always be your first port of call.

Comment: Wouldn't type checking occur at compile time regardless of `const` or `#define`?  The `define` simply inserts code which is checked at compile time.  Maybe I misunderstand what you're saying.

Answer (score -1):

If you use `#define CONST_STR "my_string"` it will be as if you used "fresh copies" of `"my_string"` everywhere.  Your compiler *might* consolidate these copies — these days many compilers do as a matter of course — or it might not.  There's also the question of whether you'd get copies consolidated across multiple translation units — modern linkers can evidently do this, but I have no idea about yours.

If you use `const char *CONST_STR = "my_string";` you are guaranteed to have exactly one copy of `"my_string"`.  And you can access it in another translation unit (i.e. in another source file) by saying `extern const char *CONST_STR;`.

Finally, if you use `const char CONST_STR[] = "my_string";` you are guaranteed to have exactly one copy of the string, and you'll save a few more bytes by not allocating an extra pointer. You can access it in another translation unit (i.e. in another source file) by saying `extern const char CONST_STR[];`.

Bottom line: I'd say definitely don't use the `#define`.  It might waste significant memory, and these days `#define` tends to be deprecated in favor of const variables anyway.

Comment: "_I doubt it would be able to consolidate them across multiple translation units._": Linkers do string merging between translation units, at least if enabled, e.g. for lld: https://manpages.debian.org/experimental/lld-10/ld.lld-10.1.en.html#O

Comment: Most linkers can merge constant strings. See the GCC option `-fmerge_constants` which puts constants into ro_data sections with the section header flag `SHF_MERGE`: "Each element in the section is compared against other elements in sections with the same name, type and flags. Elements that would have identical values at program run-time may be merged." Although only advisory, it works with ld, lld, gold, and other linkers. (Ian Lance Taylor discusses this in https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/34417.pdf, section 3.3)